# Match post title and get field data wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to match a user profile field to a category post title and then output the data from that specific post from that category. So in my user profile I have a field set as `schoolprovider` which is a text field.

I have a post category called   **local-delivery-partner-ldp** which has a post title that will match the input from `schoolprovider` and then once they match I want to output the meta fields from the post in the category schoolprovider **local-delivery-partner-ldp**

My code is as follows:

```
  // Looping through posts from my category
  $query = new WP_Query('category_name=local-delivery-partner-ldp');
  if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
  $catLdp = get_the_title();
  endwhile;
  endif;

  // Getting field from users (LDP)
  $user_info = wp_get_current_user();
  echo $user_info->schoolprovider;
  $schoolProvider = $user_info->schoolprovider;

  // Need to match $schoolProvider with the same from the category loop
  if($schoolProvider == 'SW1 Young Gloucestershire'){
  echo 'Match';
  } else{
    echo 'No Match';
  }
```

So I guess my question is how do I make a match between one of the outputs from the category loop to the output of my user meta field without hard coding it in like you can see in my `if/else` statement